# Change the Column Name in Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I trying to change the column name of the DataTable but some how I lost the data.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in item)
    Ds.Tables[0].ImportRow(dr);                           

Table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Barcode";
Table.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Description";
Table.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Price";
Table.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Cost";
Table.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Stock";
Table.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Dept #";

updateDgv.DataSource = Table;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code and it seems to work fine:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
dr[0] = "1";
dr[1] = "Name1";
table.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = table.NewRow();
dr[0] = "1";
dr[1] = "Name1";
table.Rows.Add(dr);
table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Item #";
```

Probably you are trying to access data through column name later in the code and that is where it is failing. You will not loose the data by just renaming the column name. (Also its a not a good practice use special characters in table column names)
Check out the following screen shots from data visualizer
**Before Column Rename:**
[image]

**After Column Rename:**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

First, the correct code is:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(string));
table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Item #";
```

After your code runs, you have a DataTable with one column named `Item #`.

There are no rows or data because you didn't add any data.  So you didn't lose anything.